# pchart 2.0 - Graph not displayed, when returned from function (PHP)

Tags: php, pchart

for a project I need to display the same chart with different data at the same time. The data is read from database.

Because of using the same graphs I don`t want to make an extra file for each graph.

So my Idea is to put the code of the graph to a funtion and pass the necessary arguments, like the arrays got by the sql-statements.

```
function setLineGraph ($array1...){

//includes...
//Graph code

//draw graph
    $myPicture->stroke();
}
```

With **"img src="LineGraph.php**" - File which contains the code, graph is shown.

Due to simplicity I`ve just hardcoded the values, so see if the function shows the graph.
 
So when calling it in php:
 include 'Filename.php'
**setLineGraph();**

 the error **"Graphic could not be diplayed, it has failures"** appears in the browser.

On http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.faq.script.output.html, there is written:
**Calling the Stroke() method in your script will automatically send the ‘Content-type: image/png‘ header to the user web browser and the raw picture in the HTTP GET data field.**

I have searched quite a couple of hours, but didn`t find anything to solve the problem.

Do you have any ideas how to get/ access the graph?

Comment: Sorry, ist a void function. The graph should be simply generated by by calling the function. (Of course no return.)